# Checking if index in a string is a certain letter

Tags: python, string, list

I want to make a list, that contains indices, that tell me where in a string a certain character is.

So far i have this:

```
def function(string):
    a = []
    for i in string:
        if string[i] == '*':
           a.append(i)
```

and i get an error: string indices must be integers.

I searched how to fix this, but couldn't find any suitable answers.

Comment: Using `for i in string:` sets `i` to the *characters*, not the *indices*.

Comment: Find out what `for i in string` really does.

Answer (score 0):

So remember that when you loop over an iterator the value of i takes on each element in the iterable.

So if we had:

```
for i in "Hello":
     print(i)
```

Then we would get "H", "e", "l", "l", "o".

These strings cannot be used to index a string. Instead compare i directly with *

```
def function(string):
    a = []
    for index, character in enumerate(string):
        if character == '*':
           a.append(index)
```

The enumerate function counts each iteration